Composable not recomposing when state is changed inside the ViewModel
I am trying to show a circular progress indicator, when syncing of files start by setting syncing state to true.
when syncing ends the variable becomes false.
This is the code of my MainViewModel.
public val syncing  = MutableStateFlow(false)

fun syncFiles(context: Context) {
        if ((getApplication<MainApplication>()).dropboxClient?.isClientReady() != true) {
            showShortToast(context, "Dropbox is not connected")
            return;
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            syncing.update {true}
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                var result = false;
                try {
                    getApplication<MainApplication>().initlializeDropboxFromLocalCreds()
                    updateMyData()
                    saveFiles()
                    Timber.d(bookRepo.getAllBooks().joinToString(", "))
                    result = true;
                } catch (it: Exception) {
                    Timber.tag("Error").e(it.toString())
                    result = false
                }
                syncing.update {false}
                result;
            }

            if (result) {
                showShortToast(context, "Books synced properly")
            } else {
                showShortToast(context, "Couldn't sync books")
            }
        }
}

But the state doesn't change inside the composable.
I have debugged the issue and the composable only constructs one time at start of the app.
fun MainPage(
    innerPadding: PaddingValues,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigateToReader: (filePath: String) -> Unit,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    Box {
        val state by  mainViewModel.syncing.collectAsState()
        if (state) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
//                progress = { currentProgress },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                trackColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
            )
        } else {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .padding(horizontal = 15.dp, vertical = 20.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            ) {
                Greeting(navigateToReader = navigateToReader)
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit: Added following code
Navigation code, where MainPage is navigated:
            NavHost(navController, startDestination = "main") {
                composable(
                    "reader/{file_path}",
                    arguments = listOf(navArgument("file_path") { type = NavType.StringType })
                ) { it ->
                    Log.d("Navigation", "working")
                    EpubReaderView(
                        filename = it.arguments!!.getString(
                            "file_path"
                        )!!
                    )
                }
                composable("main") {
                    val context = LocalContext.current;
                    MainPage(innerPadding = innerPadding, navigateToReader = { id ->
                        val intent = ReaderActivityContract().createIntent(
                            context, ReaderActivityContract.Arguments(id)
                        ) // filePath
                        val arguments = bundleOf("bookId" to id)
                        startActivity(context, intent, arguments)
                    })
                }
            }

Code Where the syncFiles function is called
                val getFilesActionCallback = {
                    scope.launch {
                        mainViewModel.syncFiles(context)
                    }
                }

                ListTile(
                    title = "Sync Files",
                    icon = {
                        Icon(

                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Sync,
                            contentDescription = "Sync Files"
                        )
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        getFilesActionCallback()
                        closeDrawer()
                    }
                )


I have tried mutableStateOf, remember in combination with mutableStateOf but nothing is working.
Please explain why this is happening.
I have tried debugging the issue but composable only composes once.
I expect the state to change to true on start of syncing and false when syncing ends, (which is happening).
UI should update accordingly to show circular progress indicator (which is not happening).

Could you add the code where you call the syncFiles function?

a) Key Changes in ViewModel:

Use a private MutableStateFlow (_syncing) and a public StateFlow (syncing) for better encapsulation.

Update the state using _syncing.value = true and _syncing.value = false.
 class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

 private val _syncing = MutableStateFlow(false)
 val syncing: StateFlow<Boolean> = _syncing

 fun syncFiles(context: Context) {
     if ((getApplication<MainApplication>()).dropboxClient?.isClientReady() != true) {
         showShortToast(context, "Dropbox is not connected")
         return
     }

     viewModelScope.launch {
         _syncing.value = true
         val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             var result = false
             try {
                 getApplication<MainApplication>().initlializeDropboxFromLocalCreds()
                 updateMyData()
                 saveFiles()
                 Timber.d(bookRepo.getAllBooks().joinToString(", "))
                 result = true
             } catch (it: Exception) {
                 Timber.tag("Error").e(it.toString())
                 result = false
             }
             result
         }
         _syncing.value = false

         if (result) {
             showShortToast(context, "Books synced properly")
         } else {
             showShortToast(context, "Couldn't sync books")
         }
      }
   }
}



b) Key Changes in Composable:

Observe the state using val state by mainViewModel.syncing.collectAsState().

Ensure the Box uses modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize() for proper layout.
 fun MainPage(
 innerPadding: PaddingValues,
 modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
 navigateToReader: (filePath: String) -> Unit,
 mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()) {

 val state by mainViewModel.syncing.collectAsState()

 Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
     if (state) {
         CircularProgressIndicator(
             modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
             color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
             trackColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
         )
     } else {
         Column(
             modifier = Modifier
                 .padding(innerPadding)
                 .padding(horizontal = 15.dp, vertical = 20.dp),
             verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
         ) {
             Greeting(navigateToReader = navigateToReader)
         }
      }
   }
}



By making these changes, your composable should correctly observe the syncing state and recompose when the state changes, displaying the CircularProgressIndicator when syncing and the Column when not syncing.

It's much better to use update for thread safety. Your answer is adding nothing new

I have already tried all of these, encapsulation, directly updating state. I don't think ui change is gonna have any impact.

The issue was that the MainViewModel on which i was calling the syncFiles is different from the MainViewModel which is being passed to MainPage
Due to change in route new `MainViewModel is Created

composable("main") {
                    val context = LocalContext.current;
                    MainPage(innerPadding = innerPadding, navigateToReader = { id ->
                        val intent = ReaderActivityContract().createIntent(
                            context, ReaderActivityContract.Arguments(id)
                        ) // filePath
                        val arguments = bundleOf("bookId" to id)
                        startActivity(context, intent, arguments)
                    })
                }

Solved it by passing the same view model to MainPage

                composable("main") {
                    val context = LocalContext.current;
                    MainPage(innerPadding = innerPadding, navigateToReader = { id ->
                        val intent = ReaderActivityContract().createIntent(
                            context, ReaderActivityContract.Arguments(id)
                        ) // filePath
                        val arguments = bundleOf("bookId" to id)
                        startActivity(context, intent, arguments)
                    }, mainViewModel = mainViewModel)
                }


